# Find count of summation and X

Tags: c++, math

I tried to do this:

(n-input number 1<=n<=100, firstly x=0.1)

[image]

I have to print a table with a count of summations and X-es
I tried to solve that with recursion, but it's takes very long time:(

I only want to know the algorithm.

My attempt:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int N;

  cin >> N;

  double x = 0.1, mx2 = -x*x*2;
  int i;
  double part = 1, sum = 1;

  for (i = 2; i < N; i+=2) {
    part *= mx2/((i-1)*i);
    sum += part;
    cout<<"sum= "<<sum<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculating `x^2n` note that in previous step you have `x^2(n-1)` so just required to multiply it with `x^2`.

Also for calculating `(2n)!`, in previous step you had `(2(n-1))!` so just need to multiply it by `(2n-1)*2n`.

In fact just one extra variable helps you, which holds the value of x^2n / (2n)! in each step, to just multiply it to appropriated value in next step.

**Edit:**
Your current code problem is in this line:

```
cout<<"sum= "<<sum<<endl;
```

cause cout is very time consuming job, and in each iteration of for loop you want do it.
Instead of that, if is required to have such a cout, create char stream and insert the value of your sum into this, and at last just with one cout show all results.